# Atmega168 I2C as master

Tags: c, i2c, atmega, atmel

I've been having some problems in using a Atmega168 as a I2C device. The basic setup is that the physical I2C bus is connected to other slave devices but the Atmel itself is not enabled for I2C.

There is a also a linux based TI DM365 SoC on the bus. The DM365 can communicate with the slave devices with no problem. So essentially, it's going to be a multi-master setup.

The essential atmel code is pasted below. USART_Transmit is same as printf in this case. TWIinit() is called in main() and the bus is read on command(from serial).

I keep getting "Error: 0x18", which is when the device address is not transmitted indicating the bus is busy. But when I use a voltmeter (sorry, no oscilloscope), the is held high at 3.3V, which means the bus is free to be used. I also tried this by physically cutting out the DM365, but even that didn't work.

Any help or ideas are appreciated.

EDIT: Apologize for the terrible debugging method. When I get the 'Err:0x18' it meant I never got 0x18, it just meant that's where I'm stuck. The actual value I get is 0x06, which I don't know where it's coming from.

```
uint8_t u8ebyte;
uint8_t u8erbyte;
uint16_t u16eaddress = 0x0002;
#define EEDEVADR 0x36

void TWInit (void)
{   
    TWSR = 0x00;    // prescaler 1
    TWBR = 0xFF;   //0xFF; //smallest TWBR value possible is 0x10
    TWCR = (1<<TWEN);  // Enable TWI-interface and release TWI pins.
}

void TWIStart(void)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA)|(1<<TWEN);
    while ((TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) == 0);
}
//send stop signal
void TWIStop(void)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTO)|(1<<TWEN);
}

void TWIWrite(uint8_t u8data)
{
    TWDR = u8data;
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
    while ((TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) == 0);
}

uint8_t TWIReadACK(void)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWEA);
    while ((TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) == 0);
    return TWDR;
}
//read byte with NACK
uint8_t TWIReadNACK(void)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
    while ((TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) == 0);
    return TWDR;
}

uint8_t TWIGetStatus(void)
{
    uint8_t status;
    //mask status
    status = TWSR & 0xF8;
    return status;
}

uint8_t I2CReadByte(uint16_t u16addr, uint8_t *u8data)
{
    //uint8_t databyte;
    TWIStart();
    if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x08){
        USART_Transmit_string("ERR:0x08");
        TWIStop();
       return -1;
    }
    //select device 
    TWIWrite((EEDEVADR)|((uint8_t)((u16addr& 0x0700)>>7)));

    //TWIWrite(((EEDEVADR)<<1|0));
    if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x18){
        USART_Transmit_string("ERR:0x18");
        return -1;
    }

    //send the rest of address
    TWIWrite((uint8_t)(u16addr));
    if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x28){
        USART_Transmit_string("ERR:0x28");
        return -1;
    }

    //send repeated- start
    TWIStart();
    if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x10){
        USART_Transmit_string("ERR:0x10");
        return -1;
    }

    //select devise and send read bit
    TWIWrite((EEDEVADR)|((uint8_t)((u16addr & 0x0700)>>7))|1);
    if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x40){
        USART_Transmit_string("ERR:0x40");
        return -1;
    }

    *u8data = TWIReadNACK();

    if (TWIGetStatus() != 0x58){
        USART_Transmit_string("ERR:0x58");
        return -1;
    }
    TWIStop();
    USART_Transmit_string("MADE IT!!");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: TWIGetStatus() != 0x18, checks if the status is 0x18 or something else.
If you want to debug this problem you should e.g. send the current status via uart.

0x18 means:SLA+W has been transmitted.
http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2545.pdf table 22.2

Comment: Updated my question. The current status I get is 0x06.

Answer (score 0):

Can be due to these problems:

1. Hardware
   Can be due to the improper pull up of the line and it depends on the processor/microcontroller or sensors in the bus.
2. Software
   Check the speed of the protocol(100Khz or 400KHz). It should be same for master and slave to communicate.
   Try to rewrite the code of TWI Start like this :

   ```
   void TWI_start(void){
   // Clear TWI interrupt flag, Put start condition on SDA, Enable TWI
   TWCR= (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA)|(1<<TWEN);  
   while(!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT))); // Wait till start condition is transmitted
   while((TWSR & 0xF8)!= 0x08);// Check for the acknowledgement
   }
   ```

   Here the code is waiting till the TWSR & 0xF8 becomes 0x08. Similarly rewrite the code and try!